# И снова выход за пределы массива

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-basic, исключения, datagrid

Падаем на инициализации DataGridView....

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim arr() As Integer
    Dim j, i, length As Integer
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim nullCount, positiveCount, negativeCount As Integer

    While length <= 0
        length = InputBox("Введите длину массива (неотрицательное ненулевое число):")
    End While

    ReDim arr(0 To length)

    For j = 0 To length - 1
        number = InputBox("Введите целое число (отрицательное или положительное).")
        If IsNumeric(number) Then
            arr(j) = number
        Else
            j -= 1
            MsgBox("Вводите число!")
        End If
    Next j

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = length
    DataGridView1.RowCount = 1
    negativeCount = 0
    nullCount = 0
    positiveCount = 0


    For i = 0 To length - 1
        DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value = arr(i)
        If arr(i) > 0 Then
            positiveCount += 1
        ElseIf arr(i) Like 0 Then
            nullCount += 1
        Else
            negativeCount += 1
        End If
    Next i

    Label1.Text = "Количество отрицательных элементов: " + negativeCount.ToString()
    Label2.Text = "Количество нулевых элементов: " + nullCount.ToString()
    Label3.Text = "Количество положительных элементов: " + positiveCount.ToString()

    Me.Opacity = 100
End Sub
```

Comment: А вы внутри цикла выводите на экран индекс `i` или `j` и увидите, где именно выходите за границы.

Comment: @LEQADA, я же в дебаге смотрел, выход за пределы происходит на индексе i = 1!!! При длине массива - 4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView1.Item(i, 0).value = arr(i)`, у Вас `RowCount=1`, след максимальный индекс по строке `0`, и поменяйте индексы местами, должно быть. Ссыль [DataGridView.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms158656(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Public Property Item (
  columnIndex As Integer,
  rowIndex As Integer
) As DataGridViewCell
```

Comment: Хвала небесам!!! Спасибо!!! Вы спасли мой мозг! Кто бы мог подумать, что тут всё наоборот.... После С, С++ и С# - этот Basic такая боль....

Comment: юзайте MSDN, он меня не раз выручал.